# Silverstripe: Contact Form Method Does Not Exist

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

Hey folks I'm trying to create a simple contact form for my website. I'm using ShaeDawson's blocks module.

I'm getting the following error:

> "Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'contactform' does
>   not exist on 'Block_Controller'"

Here is the code for my block:

```
<?php

class ContactBlock extends Block {
    private static $db = array(
        'ContainToGrid'     => 'Boolean',
        'SectionBGColour'   => 'Varchar',
        'GridBGColour'      => 'Varchar',
        'OverrideEmail'     => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $singular_name = 'Contact Form';
    private static $plural_name = 'Contact Forms';

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", HeaderField::create('BlockSettings', 'Block settings')->setHeadingLevel(2), "ManyMany[BlockArea]");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", CheckBoxField::create("ContainToGrid", "Contain in grid?"));

        //Background colours of section
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", TextField::create("SectionBGColour", "Block Background Colour")
            ->setDescription('(Optional) Leave blank for transparent'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", TextField::create("GridBGColour", "Grid Background Colour")
            ->setDescription('(Optional) Leave blank for transparent')
            ->displayIf('ContainToGrid')->isChecked()->end());

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", HeaderField::create('EmailNotifications', 'Email Notification')->setHeadingLevel(2));

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", TextField::create("OverrideEmail", "OverrideEmail")
            ->setDescription('(Optional) Entering an email address here will override the email set in site settings'));

        return $fields;
    }

    public function ContactForm(){
        return $this->getController()->ContactForm();
    }
}

class ContactForm_Controller extends Block_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'ContactForm'
    );

    public function ContactForm(){
        $fields = FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Name'),
            EmailField::create('Email'),
            TextField::create('Organisation'),
            TextAreaField::create('Message')
        ));
        $actions = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('submit', 'Send Enquiry')
        );
        return Form::create($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions);
    }
    public function submit($data, $form){
        // process form data as usual 
        // ...
        // redirect
        return $this->redirect($this->pageLink() . '?contacted=1');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this. Rookie mistake.

I needed to change the name of my 'Block Controller' extension from:

`ContactForm_Controller`

to:

`ContactBlock_Controller`

Ugh....